# std::vector is not accepted as delegate return type in C++/CLI? C2065 C2061

Tags: vector, delegates, c++-cli, return

I have the following C++/CLI snippet:

```
.h
#pragma unmanaged
#include <vector>

public delegate std::vector<std::wstring> XYZ(const std::wstring& filter);

.cpp

XYZ^ xyz = gcnew XYZ(&myClass::xyzFunc); // <-error C2065 + C2061
```

This case I get at this line two errors:

error C2065: 'xyz' : undeclared identifier

error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'XYZ'

However, if I change the delegate return type from vector -> wstring (for example), it works!

```
public delegate std::wstring XYZ(const std::wstring& filter); // <-- w/o vector<> , works!
```

Has anyone any idea what is the problem?
Greatly appreciated!

Comment: std::vector is not a CLR type... It would stand to reason you need to expose it as an IEnumerable/IList

Comment: nor does std::wstring ... but that works? why?

Comment: Because it gets standard conversion to clr System.String, is my guess. I'm not using C++/CLI on a daily basis, but this is my gut feeling about this. Not all native types can be marshaled as-is (integers may, some POD structs may, but likely not complicated container classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly this is a compiler defect, it should at least have emitted a diagnostic why it didn't add the delegate type to the symbol table.  You could submit it to connect.microsoft.com but they are not going to fix it.

A workaround is to use a typedef to declare the return value type:

```
typedef std::vector<std::wstring> returntype;
delegate returntype XYZ(const std::wstring& filter);
```

I would urge you a bit to treat C++/CLI as an interop language, its major reason for being.  This delegate is not usable by any other managed code.  Do favor String and `List<String^>` here.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected something strange here...
I need this delegate as a callback to a managed class as a function pointer from a native C++ lib. Complicated stuff :(
ps: why do you think they are not going to fix it?